# Configuring a Neo4j instance to use a default GRASS style

Tags: neo4j

I have developed a default style for my network that I would like to automatically apply to all Neo4j Browser instances. The style is specified using a GRASS (graph-style-sheet) file. I read in the [3.0.1 changelog](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-3.0-changelog#301) that you can apply a style from a URL with the `:style` browser command. However, **is it possible to configure a Neo4j server with a default GRASS?**

I'm using Neo4j 3.0.1. If a custom default style is not possible, are then any workarounds so users so users don't have to mess with any styling commands?

Comment: The style is set in the browser local storage, I'm afraid all users will have to issue the `:style` command.